# SOS_CACHESTORE_CLOCK Spin Lock

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017

We recently moved from SQL Server 2012 (SP3) to SQL Server 2017 via restored backup.  When we were running on 2012, performance was adequate.  Since moving to 2017 we have noticed a degradation in performance.

Digging in has shown that this may be a Write Log speed issue.  As I was trying to find more information on that I found this query for spinlocks: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-spinlock-statistics-for-a-period-of-time/

Running it shows most of my values in the low 100's.  But one value far exceeded all the others.  `SOS_CACHESTORE_CLOCK` had a value of 2,875,000 Diff Spins.  I have no idea what this is, but having it be 2,000 times larger than all the others made me worry.

Googling has shown only that this value is for "[internal use only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-spinlock-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)".

**I am asking here in hopes that someone has a hint on what this is for any why it is so high.**

Note: The value is `SOS_CACHESTORE_CLOCK`, not `SOS_CACHESTORE`.

Comment: Did you leave the compatibility level where it was, and run Query Store to gather a query performance baseline?  Per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/query-store-usage-scenarios?view=sql-server-ver15#CEUpgrade  Why are you looking a spinlocks and not wait stats? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft and Vaccano: I'm having a similar issue with SQL Server 2017 (most DBs upgraded from 2008 R2). Most have compatibility level of 140. I can't speak for the O.P., but I was looking at spinlocks because it was mentioned in this presentation: [TempDB: The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly by Pam Lahoud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JPFy19yL7k). In my system the value for `SOS_CACHESTORE_CLOCK` is about 10x the next highest one, which I think was something like `OBJECTSTORE_CACHE`. Is `SOS_CACHESTORE_CLOCK` one of those internal, ever-present items that should be ignored?